# Catching bad passwords when using LDAP

Tags: coldfusion, ldap, try-catch, coldfusion-9

I use LDAP to authenticate users on my app.

```
<cftry>
    <cfldap action="query"
      name      ="qryAuth"
      attributes="cn,displayname,mail"
      start     ="DC=corp,DC=com"
      server    ="#LDAPserver#"
      filter    = "(cn=#arguments.EID#)"
      username  ="corp\#arguments.EID#"
      password  ="#arguments.password#">

    <cfset this.addlog(arguments.EID, "Success on #LDAPserver#")>
    <cfreturn true>

    <cfcatch>

        <cfset this.addlog(arguments.EID, "#cfcatch.message# on #LDAPserver#")>

        <cfif cfcatch.message CONTAINS "error code 49">
```

Error code 49 is when a user enters a bad password. Every time this is ran an error is logged. Is there a way to check for passwords via LDAP without using try/catch?

Comment: I just checked the way we do it, and we use try/catch.

Comment: I always use try/catch as well. Is there a reason you don't want to do that? You can always check for different errors to perform different logic (as you appear to be doing).

Comment: I don't like that every catch statement gets logged in the CF admin.

Comment: Move your logging code so that the 49 errors (and any others you don't care about) do not get logged. You must be talking about something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a pre-parse plugin that performs the BIND before the server performs the operation and sets a well-known condition indicating he BIND would have failed. Professional-quality LDAP server provide the described functionality out of the box.